# Changing hosts file in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, hosts

I came here to ask you how to set up my hosts file in Ubuntu so when I go to **95.42.251.194:3333** my browser to open **127.0.0.1** .

I tried this:
**127.0.0.1 95.42.251.194:3333**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` (or it's equivalents on other OS's) is used to *resolve* hostnames to some ip without asking to dns servers.

You can use in your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.com
```

And then open `http://myserver.com:3333` in your browser and it will connect to `127.0.0.1` to `3333` port.

You can NOT map ip addresses with `/etc/hosts`.

You can use iptables for this. But that's another question.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/ shows how to do the port mapping.

Comment: My original answer was approved to change by other users. Originally there were:
-------------------------------
You can use in your /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 mysuperserver
-------------------------------
This is ok and works in any OS. Probably suggested change by adding port to hosts record (127.0.0.1 mysuperserver:3333) works in some OS, but it's surely does not work in linux.